Dropdown Menu Icon and Text Misalignment Issue
I'm working on creating a dropdown menu where the parent menu item includes an icon and text. However, I'm encountering an issue where the parent menu text does not align properly with the icon, causing the entire menu to shift to the right.
Check this output
Here’s the HTML and CSS code I’m using:
HTML
<div class="dashboard">
    <i class="fa fa-database" ></i>
    <button class="dropdown-btn">Master Data
       <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-container">
       <a href="#">Data Siswa</a>
       <a href="#">Data Staff</a>
       <a href="#">Data Penerbit</a>
    </div>
</div>

CSS
.sidenav .dashboard {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: max-content max-content;
    grid-template-rows: max-content;
    gap: 5px;
    align-items: center;
}

Issue:
The parent menu text is not aligning properly with the icon, causing the entire menu to shift to the right when it is clicked. I want the text and icon to be exactly side by side without any misalignment. How can I fix this alignment issue?

Can you provide a minimal reproducible example so contributors can help you with your problem? Also please read how to ask a good question. You'll get better answers if you follow this guidance.
